# Spring boot Restful API: DTO with relationships convert to entity using ModelMapper?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, modelmapper

I'm now confused about how to do a CRUD in a Rest API with Spring.

Let me explain, I have two routes to POST and PUT an entity. I created two DTOs `createPostRequest` and `updatePostRequest` for this. Because when adding, the properties cannot be null, while when updating they can (nulled properties are ignored).

**Problem 1:**

On my frontend, the user is asked to choose a list of tags from the database (multi select html). This is why `createPostRequest` has a `tags` property typed `TagDTO`. But, how can I use modelMapper to map, for example, the `createPostRequest` to the `Post` entity making sure that the tags exist in the database?

if for example a user try to insert a tag that does not exist, I was thinking of doing something like this:

```java
postEntity.setTags(tagService.findAllByIds(postEntity.getTagsId()));
```

This makes a lot of repetition in the code, because between create and update method of my entity in service, there is a lot of identical code.

**Problem 2:**

Based on my problem 1, how can I easily map my two DTOs to the same entity without repeating the code 2x?

**Code example -** `PostService` **(see comment)**

This is an example for the update, but there will be almost identical code for the `create`, so how do I proceed?

```java
@Transactional
public Post update(Integer postId, UpdatePostRequest request) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(this.getById(postId)).map(post -> {
      // here how to map non-null properties of my request 
            // into my post taking in consideration my comment above?   

      postDAO.save(post);

      return post;
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
}
```

================================

**UPDATE:**

As requested, found the code bellow.

The controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/posts")
public class PostController {
    RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> update(@Valid @RequestBody CreatePostRequest createPostRequest) {
        Post post = postService.create(createPostRequest);
        return new ApiResponseHandler(new PostDTO(post), HttpStatus.OK).response();
    }

    RequestMapping(value = "/{postId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> update(@Valid @RequestBody UpdatePostRequest updatePostRequest, @PathVariable Integer postId) {
        Post post = postService.update(postId, updatePostRequest);
        return new ApiResponseHandler(new PostDTO(post), HttpStatus.OK).response();
    }
}
```

CreatePostRequest :

```
@Data
public class CreatePostRequest {
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 10, max = 30)
    private Sting title;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 50, max = 600)
    private String description

    @NotNull
    @ValidDateString
    private String expirationDate;

    @NotNull
    private List<TagDTO> tags;

    public List<Integer> getTagIds() {
        return this.getTags().stream().map(TagDTO::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

UpdatePostRequest :

```
@Data
public class UpdatePostRequest {
    @Size(min = 10, max = 30)
    private Sting title;

    @Size(min = 50, max = 600)
    private String description

    @ValidDateString
    private String expirationDate;

    private List<TagDTO> tags;

    public List<Integer> getTagIds() {
        return this.getTags().stream().map(TagDTO::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

The service :

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PostService {
    @Transactional
    public Post create(CreatePostRequest request) {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        Post post = modelMapper.map(request, Post.class);

        // map will not work for tags : how to check that tags exists in database ?

        return postDAO.save(post);
    }

    @Transactional
    public Post update(Integer postId, UpdatePostRequest request) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(this.getById(postId)).map(post -> {
            ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
            modelMapper.getConfiguration().setSkipNullEnabled(true);
            modelMapper.map(request, post);
            
            // map will not work for tags : how to check that tags exists in database ?
            
            postDAO.save(post);

            return post;
        }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to add more code so that we can help you. Starting with `UpdatePostRequest`, `CreatePostRequest`, the Controller that exposes both endpoints and also the code for `update` and `create` methods. Thanks!

Comment: @JoãoDias I added the code as requested, but please note that the service methods are not finished because I just don't know how to properly comment out my request as an entity while validating the tag relationship to ensure it exists. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid duplication of two similar DTOs you could use `@Validated` group validations. This allows you to actively set which validations are to be done on each property. You can read more about this in the following online resource https://www.baeldung.com/spring-valid-vs-validated. You would begin with the creation of two market interfaces:

```java
interface OnCreate {}

interface OnUpdate {}
```

You can then use these marker interfaces with any constraint annotation in your common DTO:

```java
@Data
public class CreateOrUpdatePostRequest {
    @NotNull(groups = OnCreate.class)
    @Size(min = 10, max = 30, groups = {OnCreate.class, OnUpdate.class})
    private Sting title;

    @NotNull(groups = OnCreate.class)
    @Size(min = 50, max = 600, groups = {OnCreate.class, OnUpdate.class})
    private String description

    @NotNull(groups = OnCreate.class)
    @ValidDateString(groups = {OnCreate.class, OnUpdate.class})
    private String expirationDate;

    @NotNull(groups = OnCreate.class)
    private List<TagDTO> tags;

    public List<Integer> getTagIds() {
        return this.getTags().stream().map(TagDTO::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Finally, you just need to annotate your methods in the Controller accordingly:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/posts")
@Validated
public class PostController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> update(@Validated(OnCreate.class) @RequestBody CreateOrUpdatePostRequest createPostRequest) {
        Post post = postService.create(createPostRequest);
        return new ApiResponseHandler(new PostDTO(post), HttpStatus.OK).response();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{postId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> update(@Validated(OnUpdate.class) @RequestBody CreateOrUpdatePostRequest updatePostRequest, @PathVariable Integer postId) {
        Post post = postService.update(postId, updatePostRequest);
        return new ApiResponseHandler(new PostDTO(post), HttpStatus.OK).response();
    }
}
```

With this, you can have a single mapping function.

Still, keep in mind that using validation groups can easily become an anti-pattern given that we are mixing different concerns. With validation groups, the validated entity has to know the validation rules for all the use cases it is used in. Having said that, I usually avoid using validation groups unless it is really necessary.

---

Regarding `tags` I guess your only option is to query the database. The ones that do not exist you should create them (I guess), so something along the following lines:

```java
List<Integer> tagsId = createOrUpdatePostRequest.getTagsId();
List<Tag> tags = tagService.findAllByIds(tagsId);
List<Integer> nonExistentTagsId = tagsId.stream().filter(id -> tags.stream().noneMatch(tag -> tag.getId().equals(id)));
if (!nonExistentTagsId.isEmpty()) {
    // create Tags and add them to tags List
}
```

Comment: I'll try like this! Thank you very much for your answer. For the two market interfaces, where do you store them in your architecture? In a specific folder?

Comment: Have you tried this? Did it work? I would put them on a specific folder in a `dto` subpackage. Something like `dto.validation` or similar.

Comment: Yes and it's not working. I have changed the `@Valid` annotation before `@RequestBody` by the `@Validated(OnCreate.class)` annotation and now it's ok.
And if I apply a rule like `@ValidDateString`, i have to add the two groups if i want that the validation works. The rule is not applied by default to all groups, I do not know why.

Comment: Well, now I am confused. Is it working or not? Regarding `@Validated(OnCreate.class)` that was my mistake. I copied your code and placed it in the wrong place. I've changed my answer. Regarding `@ValidDateString`, this is a custom annotation right?

Comment: Yes it works now and yes it is a custom validation. But it's the same problem with `@Size` for example. `@Size` will not apply to Create or Update. I have to add `@Size(groups = {onCreate.class, onUpdate.class})`

Comment: Then if it is working consider upvoting my answer and accepting it as the correct answer so that it can be ”closed” and others can benefit from it and easily understand which could be a possible solution for similar questions ;) Thanks!

Comment: For sure, I just had a very big refactoring job this week and was waiting until I was done to upvote it all. Thanks again for your help!